# Why do dictionaries use non-standard IPA symbols

Tags: ipa, dictionary

"ɛə̯" or "ɛə" can be written as  "ea"  "ɛː" "ɛ" and "ɛə" in various dictionaries.
http://teflpedia.com/IPA_phoneme_/e%C9%99/
 I don't see the value as they aren't fixing the non-intuitive nature of IPA symbols "j" as y sound is still standard.
http://teflpedia.com/IPA_phoneme_/e%C9%99/
Why change when it doesn't make the reading of the symbols any easier- you still need to memorise them?

Comment: You may want to give us some links where you noticed such symbols. I can be result of a typo of simply misconfigured fonts.

Comment: You can find similar in the many dictionaries.

Comment: many English dictionaries write /ɛ/ as /e/ due to "tradition", which means for no good reason, really (also /ʌ/ for what's more of an [ɐ], and /ɒ/ for an [ɔ]—this kinda thing confused the hell out of me when I was learning English). /ɛː/ vs. /ɛə/ sounds like dialectal variation to me, or different analyses; while 'ea' is probably a lazy way of typing /ɛɐ/, which I think I can hear e.g. in certain RP pronunciations of "somewhere".

Comment: Is it regional dictionaries you are talking about?

Comment: @leoboiko the usage of /e/ over /ɛ/ is indeed actually proper IPA usage; the principles of IPA generally state that 1) " if two sounds contrast in any language, there should be a difference in the transcription convention to indicate this difference", and 2) "use Roman characters as much as possible"; since English /e/ doesn't contrast with /ɛ/, it is safe to use one phoneme, which can be said to be /e/, that is orthographically the simplest one possible for such a span of allophones.

Comment: @Darkgamma: sure, as long as you don't mind confusing a few million ESL learners every year who will, as I did, assume naturally that the sound in 'bed' has the same vowel quality as the first half of the diphthong in "aim", since that scheme would transcribe those as /bed/ and /eɪm/ – with no discernible advantage except being easier for lazy typists to type. But if "orthographic simplicity" is more important than "clarity for people who need help with pronunciation", who are the pronunciation guides *for*? Native speakers?

Comment: @Darkgamma: In retrospect, your comment was polite and informative, and my reply was abrasive for no reason. Sorry for that.

Comment: @leoboiko the acoustic difference between the <bed> and <aim> vowels isn't fit for a phonemic transcription: they would necessarily (according to (all?) current linguistic conventions) have to be distinguished in square brackers as [bɛd] and [e͡ɪ̯m], though a question arises of where one'd draw the line; I can anecdotally claim to have heard <aim> from [æ͡ɪ̯m] to [eːm] — there isn't even one standard pronunciation, so a phoneme list is useful if the speaker knows how his chosen target accent transforms its phonemes into phones.

Answer (score 7):

IPA is only a set of symbols and approximate phonetic values, and there is no mandate to transcribe English words any particular way. The variants [eə, ɛə, ɛə̯, ɛː] are all within IPA, and the labeling of [ɛə̯] as "strict IPA" is a misnomer: There is no such thing as "strict IPA", there is IPA, or not IPA (as in traditional dictionary "trän-SKRIP-shun"). It is possible that [ɛə̯] is specifically taught by UCL or used in Jones dictionary, but IPA does not officially sanction any particular transcription practices for languages.

Dictionaries correctly tend to avoid narrow phonetic transcriptions, since they tend to reflect individual idiosyncracies. Instead, they give broad phonemic transcriptions which describe a wider range of language forms (though for English it's really impossible to give a single form that generalizes to all dialects), and then leave it to the user to discern how "square" i.e. [skwɛɹ] is pronounced in a particular region.

Comment: If that is true then IPA has two "r"s - the trilled one and the one   that is written in just about every English dictionary's IPA script- so much for one character one sound. Also the upside "r" that is written as the correct r for English.